# use of separate sequence for tables in hibernate envers

Tags: hibernate, logging, audit, hibernate-envers, audit-logging

I know that hibernate envers uses same sequence for all the audit tables it generates but in my database there are more than 100 tables and they contain millions of data records so I want to use separate sequence for all the tables. Kindly suggest me how to achieve this because I am not able to find anything related to my problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately currently the Envers revisions are global per Hibernate configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply adam.. My suggestion would be to incorporate separate sequence for different tables in upcoming version of envers and thanks for giving us the hibernate envers :)